# Execute external script in ExtendScript for Illustrator

Tags: python, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Summary:

Is there a way to use the execute() function to pass a parameter to a Python script, and have the Python script use the parameter in its execution, then return the result to ExtendScript?

Context:
I'm building a script for Illustrator that has to query a web service, process the resultant XML file, and return the results to the user. This would be easy if I were using one of the applications that support the Socket feature, but Illustrator doesn't. My next thought, was that I can achieve the HTTP request and XML parsing in Python. I'm at a loss on how to bridge the two.

Comment: Had to do this type of thing for After Effects.  See this discussion thread:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/5685925#5685925

Comment: If you're using Illustrator CS6, it seems to support a `Socket` class.

Answer (score 4):

## Option 1 (BridgeTalk)

I had to do something like this to run an external PNG processor from both Photoshop and Illustrator. <strike>Neither of those applications have the ability to execute external programs from ExtendScript.</strike> (See Option 2.) Adobe Bridge's `app` object has a `system` method that executes a command in the system shell. Using a `BridgeTalk` object, you can call that method remotely from Illustrator. You'll only get the exit code in return, though. So you'll need to redirect your program's output to a file and then read that file in your script.

Here's an example of using `BridgeTalk` and Adobe Bridge to run an external program:

```
var bt = new BridgeTalk();
bt.target = 'bridge';
bt.body = 'app.system("ping -c 1 google.com")';
bt.onResult = function (result) {
    $.writeln(result.body);
};
bt.send();
```

### Pros

- Asynchronous
- Can easily retrieve the exit code
- Can use shell syntax and pass arguments to the program directly

### Cons

- Adobe Bridge must be installed
- Adobe Bridge must be running (although BridgeTalk will launch it for you, if needed)

## Option 2 (File.prototype.execute)

I discovered this later and can't believe I missed it. The `File` class has an `execute` instance method that opens or executes the file. It might work for your purposes, although I haven't tried it myself.

### Pros

- Asynchronous
- Built into each ExtendScript environment (no inter-process communication)

### Cons

- Can't retrieve the exit code
- Can't use shell syntax or pass arguments to the program directly

Comment: This is an interesting proposal. I'm going to give this a try and see if it works for me.

Comment: @HasecBinUsr I've updated my answer with an alternative option, in case the first doesn't work for you.

Comment: Do you have any idea if option 1 will actually open Bridge and run assuming CS6 is run virtually on some clients' machines? Also, it seems option 2 is more versatile, but without being able to retrieve external output, I'm not sure it's very useful. Perhaps pass the arguments to an XML file like a SOAP/REST call, read/process with the external script, and update the XML with the response in the project directory that ExtendScript then inputs...

Comment: Adobe Bridge will launch and be visible to the user. I'm not sure what you mean by CS6 being run virtually. As long as Bridge is installed alongside Illustrator, it should work. As for passing data back and forth with option 2, your idea should work (especially since ExtendScript supports XML) and would also be valid for option 1.

Comment: Most users have some components of CS6 available as virtual applications. Servers host the actual install and serve it out through something like a Citrix receiver. My concern is that because they don't have a local install, Bridge would not actually launch and the command would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Extendscript does support Socket, following is the code snippet

```
reply = "";
conn = new Socket;
// access Adobe’s home page
if (conn.open ("www.adobe.com:80")) {
// send a HTTP GET request
conn.write ("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n");
// and read the server’s reply
reply = conn.read(999999);
conn.close();
}
```