# Passing the result of a python script to an ExtendScript `.jsx` file

Tags: python, google-sheets, jsx, extendscript

So, I'm writing a python script that gets data from a google sheet and returns it back to an ExtendScript script that I'm writing for After Effects.

The relevant bits are :

**getSpreadsheetData.py**

```
def main():
    values = getSpreadsheetRange("1M337m3YHCdCDcVyS4fITvAGJsw7rGQ2XGbZaKIdkJPc", "A1:Q41")
    return processValues(values)
```

**afterEffectsScript.jsx**

```
var script_file = File("getSpreadsheetData.py");
var results = script_file.execute();
$.writeln(results);
alert("done!");
```

So, I have three questions :

1. How do I pass variables from the `afterEffectsScript.jsx` to the python script (for example the spreadsheet id and range)?
2. How do I get a return from the python script and return it back to the `jsx` file?
3. How do I make my `afterEffectsScript` to work async so that it can wait for the python script to get what it needs...

Thanks in advance for the advice!

-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Effects has the possibility to call system commands and get the result of `stdout`.

```
var cmd = "pwd";
var stdout = system.callSystem(cmd);
$.writeln(stdout);
```

Take a look into the [AE Scripting Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables via setting environment variables. 
Small example how call external script with args from extendscript:

```
var script_file = File("getSpreadsheetData.py");
$.setenv("arg_1", "arg1_value");
$.setenv("arg_2", "arg2_value");
script_file.execute();
```

You python script should start with reading this varibles from environment: [Access environment variables from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/access-environment-variables-from-python)

Comment: Aha, this sounds like a solution to points #1 & #2!  Is there a way of listening to when environmental variables change values to answer point #3?  I assume that I'd then manipulate a environmental variable from python & access it from the ExtendScript rather than use the `results` variable as I've done here?

Comment: Other issues are discussed here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969372/execute-external-script-in-extendscript-for-illustrator